# How to Clone Function with relative Reference on HSSF apache poi (JAVA)

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm try to make a export Excel, and i need some formula for count number in my excel , but i have a data from database and it will be more than one. so i wanna clone that formula to next data.

it goes well , but the reference cell can't change to next cell, like if we tried copy cell from excel

```
cellOne[data].setCellFormula(celltwo[data].getCellFormula());
```

[i want to copy count from data1 to data2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIb8N.png)

Comment: Could you show more of your code? Your single line of code is just not enough for anyone to help you.

Comment: i think , that is the point for clone my cell to another cell, i using that method, to get my formula from celltwo and drop it at cellOne

Comment: The formula to be set is a `String` containing cell and row references. That's why it does not work if you just copy the formula from one cell and paste it into another, which would work via Excel-GUI by mouse/keyboard. You could create a class representing the formula and give it some attributes that have to be adjusted to the new cell or row numbers along with a proper `toString()` or `toExcelFormula()` method.

Comment: Could you add the formula to your question by [editing it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57072729/edit)?

Comment: Question edited, hope u understand @deHaar

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47594254/apache-poi-update-formula-references-when-copying/47606426#47606426

Comment: Are you sure you don't want the real formula `SUM(H20;I20)` instead of directly summing `H20+I20`?

Comment: it's ok , for using SUM(H20;I20) but i still need a method to copy that cell @deHaar

Comment: You could provide the formula as a `String` template that takes arguments, like `String sumFormulaTemplate = "SUM(H%d;I%d)";` (columns are hard coded here). Then you could loop and set the row number, like `String sumFormula = String.format(sumFormulaTemplate, rowNumber, rowNumber);` and set that in column J via `cell.setFormula(sumFormula);`. If you need to read a formula first (because you don't know what formula it is or similar), you will have to find the row numbers in it and replace them with the currently needed one.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of manipulating the formula strings to update formula references, best practice is really using a `FormulaParser` in my opinion. Advantage is that really all possible formulas can be updated as long as the `FormulaParser` knows them. Manipulating the formula strings easily leads to problems. For example a formula template like `"SUM(H%d;I%d)"` has `%d` as a variable to be replaced. But the percent sign could also be a not variable part in some formulas.

The `apache poi` has a `FormulaParser` which can be used. In [Apache POI update formula references when copying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47594254/apache-poi-update-formula-references-when-copying/47606426#47606426) I have shown this already for  `XSSF` only.

Since this question is about `HSSF` I will show an `String copyFormula(Sheet sheet, String formula, int coldiff, int rowdiff)` method which works for `SS` that is for `HSSF`as well as for `XSSF`.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.formula.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.formula.ptg.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFEvaluationWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFEvaluationWorkbook;

public class ExcelCopyFormula {

 private static String copyFormula(Sheet sheet, String formula, int coldiff, int rowdiff) {

  Workbook workbook = sheet.getWorkbook();
  EvaluationWorkbook evaluationWorkbook = null;
  if (workbook instanceof HSSFWorkbook) {
   evaluationWorkbook = HSSFEvaluationWorkbook.create((HSSFWorkbook) workbook);
  } else if (workbook instanceof XSSFWorkbook) {
   evaluationWorkbook = XSSFEvaluationWorkbook.create((XSSFWorkbook) workbook);
  }

  Ptg[] ptgs = FormulaParser.parse(formula, (FormulaParsingWorkbook)evaluationWorkbook, 
   FormulaType.CELL, sheet.getWorkbook().getSheetIndex(sheet));

  for (int i = 0; i < ptgs.length; i++) {
   if (ptgs[i] instanceof RefPtgBase) { // base class for cell references
    RefPtgBase ref = (RefPtgBase) ptgs[i];
    if (ref.isColRelative())
     ref.setColumn(ref.getColumn() + coldiff);
    if (ref.isRowRelative())
     ref.setRow(ref.getRow() + rowdiff);
   }
   else if (ptgs[i] instanceof AreaPtgBase) { // base class for range references
    AreaPtgBase ref = (AreaPtgBase) ptgs[i];
    if (ref.isFirstColRelative())
     ref.setFirstColumn(ref.getFirstColumn() + coldiff);
    if (ref.isLastColRelative())
     ref.setLastColumn(ref.getLastColumn() + coldiff);
    if (ref.isFirstRowRelative())
     ref.setFirstRow(ref.getFirstRow() + rowdiff);
    if (ref.isLastRowRelative())
     ref.setLastRow(ref.getLastRow() + rowdiff);
   }
  }

  formula = FormulaRenderer.toFormulaString((FormulaRenderingWorkbook)evaluationWorkbook, ptgs);
  return formula;
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  //String type = "XSSF";
  String type = "HSSF";

  try (Workbook workbook = ("XSSF".equals(type))?new XSSFWorkbook():new HSSFWorkbook(); 
       FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(("XSSF".equals(type))?"Excel.xlsx":"Excel.xls") ) {

   Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();

   for (int r = 2 ; r < 10; r++) {
    Row row = sheet.createRow(r);
    for (int c = 2 ; c < 5; c++) {
     Cell cell = row.createCell(c);
     if (r == 2) {
      if (c == 2) cell.setCellValue("No");
      if (c == 3) cell.setCellValue("Number One");
      if (c == 4) cell.setCellValue("Number Two");
     } else {
      if (c == 2) cell.setCellValue("data" + (r-2));
      if (c == 3) cell.setCellValue(r*c);
      if (c == 4) cell.setCellValue(r*c);
     }
    }
   }

   for (int r = 2 ; r < 10; r++) {
    Row row = sheet.getRow(r);
    Cell cell = row.createCell(5);
    String formula = "D4+E4";
    if (r == 2) cell.setCellValue("Formula");
    else cell.setCellFormula(copyFormula(sheet, formula, 0, r-3));
   }

   for (int r = 2 ; r < 10; r++) {
    Row row = sheet.getRow(r);
    Cell cell = row.createCell(6);
    String formula = "G4+F5";
    if (r == 2) cell.setCellValue("Cumulative");
    else if (r == 3) cell.setCellFormula("F4");
    else cell.setCellFormula(copyFormula(sheet, formula, 0, r-4));
   }

   workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator().evaluateAll();
   workbook.write(out);

  }
 }
}
```