# Copy row formula with range in excel

Tags: android, excel-formula, apache-poi

I'm creating an application in which I'm generating an excel sheet after some inputs from the user.
If user enter 5 records, I'm coping the initial/first row(cells with formulas) and then inserting each values in cells. The problem is after coping row, the formula range doesn't being updated for eg. if initial row is **10th** and cell **A** has a formula like **SUM(G10:K10)** then after coping the row **10th** to **11th** formula remains the same i.e **SUM(G10:K10)** instead of **SUM(G11:K11)**.
Can anyone help me to solve this problem. Here's the code

```
HSSFSheet existingSheet = existingWorkBook.getSheetAt(0);
ExcelFile.copyRow(existingWorkBook, existingSheet, startRowColumn - 2, startRowColumn - 1);


public static void copyRow(HSSFWorkbook workbook, HSSFSheet worksheet, int sourceRowNum, int destinationRowNum) {
    // Get the source / new row
    HSSFRow newRow = worksheet.getRow(destinationRowNum);
    HSSFRow sourceRow = worksheet.getRow(sourceRowNum);

    // If the row exist in destination, push down all rows by 1 else create a new row
    if (newRow != null) {
        worksheet.shiftRows(destinationRowNum, worksheet.getLastRowNum(), 1);
    } else {
        newRow = worksheet.createRow(destinationRowNum);
    }

    // Loop through source columns to add to new row
    for (int i = 0; i < sourceRow.getLastCellNum(); i++) {
        // Grab a copy of the old/new cell
        HSSFCell oldCell = sourceRow.getCell(i);
        HSSFCell newCell = newRow.createCell(i);

        // If the old cell is null jump to next cell
        if (oldCell == null) {
            newCell = null;
            continue;
        }

        // Copy style from old cell and apply to new cell
        HSSFCellStyle newCellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
        newCellStyle.cloneStyleFrom(oldCell.getCellStyle());
        ;
        newCell.setCellStyle(newCellStyle);

        // If there is a cell comment, copy
        if (oldCell.getCellComment() != null) {
            newCell.setCellComment(oldCell.getCellComment());
        }

        // If there is a cell hyperlink, copy
        if (oldCell.getHyperlink() != null) {
            newCell.setHyperlink(oldCell.getHyperlink());
        }

        // Set the cell data type
        newCell.setCellType(oldCell.getCellType());

        // Set the cell data value
        switch (oldCell.getCellType()) {
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
                newCell.setCellValue(oldCell.getStringCellValue());
                break;
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                newCell.setCellValue(oldCell.getBooleanCellValue());
                break;
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR:
                newCell.setCellErrorValue(oldCell.getErrorCellValue());
                break;
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA:
                newCell.setCellFormula(oldCell.getCellFormula());
                break;
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                newCell.setCellValue(oldCell.getNumericCellValue());
                break;
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                newCell.setCellValue(oldCell.getRichStringCellValue());
                break;
        }
    }

    // If there are are any merged regions in the source row, copy to new row
    for (int i = 0; i < worksheet.getNumMergedRegions(); i++) {
        CellRangeAddress cellRangeAddress = worksheet.getMergedRegion(i);
        if (cellRangeAddress.getFirstRow() == sourceRow.getRowNum()) {
            CellRangeAddress newCellRangeAddress = new CellRangeAddress(newRow.getRowNum(),
                    (newRow.getRowNum() + (cellRangeAddress.getLastRow() - cellRangeAddress.getFirstRow())), cellRangeAddress.getFirstColumn(),
                    cellRangeAddress.getLastColumn());
            worksheet.addMergedRegion(newCellRangeAddress);
        }
    }


}
```

After coping a row, here's the code to insert cell values.

```
Iterator rowIter = existingSheet.rowIterator();
while (rowIter.hasNext()) {
            HSSFRow oldRow = (HSSFRow) rowIter.next();
            if (rowCounterOld >= startRowColumn - 2 && !isRecordInserted) {
                if (configFieldsIndexes != null && configFieldsIndexes.size() > 0) {
                    for (Map.Entry entry : configFieldsIndexes.entrySet()) {
                        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry1 : valueMap.entrySet()) {
                            if (((Map.Entry) entry1).getKey().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(entry.getKey().toString())) {
                                try {
                                    float value = Float.valueOf(entry1.getValue());
                                    oldRow.getCell(ExcelFile.getExcelColumnNumber(entry.getValue().toString())).setCellValue(value);
                                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                    oldRow.getCell(ExcelFile.getExcelColumnNumber(entry.getValue().toString())).setCellValue(entry1.getValue());
                                }

                                break;
                            }
                        }

                    }
                    isRecordInserted = true;
                    lastInsertedRow = rowCounterOld;

                }
            }
            rowCounterOld++;
            //rowCounterNew++;
        }

HSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateAllFormulaCells(existingWorkBook);
```

Comment: add all the relevant code please

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47594254/apache-poi-update-formula-references-when-copying/47606426#47606426 for a `copyFormula` method.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an initial formula in **A10**, then simple use the VBA `Copy` method to fill **A11**:

```
Sub KopyFormula()
    Dim A10 As Range, A11 As Range

    Set A10 = Range("A10")
    Set A11 = Range("A11")

    A10.Copy A11
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: How to do that in android?