# How do I emulate Excel's "Fill down" in Apache POI?

Tags: excel, apache-poi

I've got a template workbook, with a sheet ("All data") which I populate using Apache POI. I don't know how many rows I'm going to need in "All data" when I start.

In another sheet (call it "Calc"), I have 4 columns containing formulae that do stuff based on "All data". I need to have as many rows in Calc as in "All data", and I thought the easiest way to do it would be to have, in the template, one row with the formulae in it, which I can then fill down the sheet as many times as necessary.

Thus, in the template I have:

```
 Col1Header     | Col2Header                            | Col3Header                            | Col4Header
=+'All data'!F2 | =IF(LEFT(A55,1)="4",'All data'!R2,"") | =IF(LEFT(A55,1)="4",'All data'!O2,"") | =+'All data'!W2
```

Then I would expect to be able to "fill down" from that first formula line, so that I have n rows (where n is the number of rows I'm using in the "All data" sheet).

However, I cannot see how to do "fill down" in Apache POI. Is it something that's not possible? Or am I looking for the wrong name?

Yes, an alternative method would be simply to change the template by manually copying down more rows than I would ever expect to be using, but that is (a) inelegant and (b) is asking for trouble in the future:-)

I feel sure there must be a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is for an `Office Open XML` workbook (`*.xlsx`, `XSSF`) and current `apache poi 5.0.0` is used, then [XSSFSheet.copyRows](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFSheet.html#copyRows-int-int-int-org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellCopyPolicy-) can be used. The default `CellCopyPolicy` copies formulas and adjusts the cell references in them.

Example:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

class ExcelReadCopyRowsAndWrite {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  String fileIn= "./TestIn.xlsx";
  String fileOut= "./TestOut.xlsx";

  int n = 10; // 10 rows needed

  int fillRowsFromIdx = 1; // start at row 2 (index 1) which is row having the formulas
  int fillRowsToIdx = fillRowsFromIdx + n - 1;

  try (Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(fileIn));
       FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fileOut)) {

   Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("Calc"); // do it in sheet named "Calc"
   if (sheet instanceof XSSFSheet) {
    XSSFSheet xssfSheet = (XSSFSheet) sheet;
    for (int i = fillRowsFromIdx; i < fillRowsToIdx; i++) {
     xssfSheet.copyRows(i, i, i+1, new CellCopyPolicy());
    }
   }

   workbook.write(out);
  } 
 }
}
```

The`copyRows` method is only in `XSSF` up to now. For an example how to copy formulas also working for `BIFF` workbook (`*.xls`, `HSSF`) see [Apache POI update formula references when copying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47594254/apache-poi-update-formula-references-when-copying/47606426#47606426).